# Using weighted or unweighted wPCA scores in Logistic regression model-SAS

Tags: logistic, pca, sas, weighted-data, factor-rotation

Im working on data that I should weight the data using a weight variable that I have and I want to evaluate the association of dietary pattern and obesity. So first I run Proc factor and use the "Weight" option to get the factors loading on each factor and also the factor scores. Then I interpret them and say Factor one is a "Healthy" dietary pattern. 
Then for putting into the logistic regression, I dont put the weighted scores but I run again the PROC factor this time without using the "Weight" option. The reason is because I think that all variables that we put in the model should be similarly unweighted. So I Put this unweighted factor scores in my logistic model as an independent variable. The problem is that Unweighted scores and weighted scores are different and they are different dietary patterns, So I'm not sure if when I put the unweighted scores in the model does it first weight them and deal with them as my "healthy" weighted dietary pattern? and is the Odds ratio the logistic regression giving my is it regarding the weighted "Healthy" dietary pattern or is it regarding the "unweighted" dietary pattern that is actually an "Unhealthy dietary pattern.